# how to use natural language generation from a csv file input .which python module we should use.can any one share a sample tutorial?

Tags: python, nlp

take a input as a csv file and generate text/sentence using nlg. I have tried with pynlg and markov chain.But nothing worked .What else I can use?

Answer (score 0):

The Python library `nlglib` can certainly generate good grammatical text for you. But you will have to spend some time learning how to program the natural language generating model that it exposes. In summary, you supply the key-content to the natural language model you create and it will generate natural text.

Broadly speaking the steps you take will be:

- Extract the relevant data from your CSV data.
- Build an NLG model or outline, of the general form you want your natural language to take.
- Substitute the appropriate parts of the NLG model with your specific data
- Have the model `realize` the text output.

Step 2 takes some learning not only in the parts of speech but, also, in the model's API.

Answer (score -1):

There are not much python libraries for NLG!!. Try out nlglib a python wrapper around SimpleNLG. For tutorial purposes, you could read Building Natural Language Generation systems by e.reiter.